# C# GC delegates?

Tags: c#, events, delegates, garbage-collection

How can I know when GC starts? Can I give to GC some delegates for such events like "OnStart" and "OnEnd"?

Comment: If you want/"need" to do this, your idea is propably a bad and/or batshit insane one. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Your program stops running when GC starts, so what would you do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to to when GC happens you can create an object which has a finalizer and immeditaly set the reference to it to null. This way, the object if still generation 0 and will **likely** garbage collected the next time the GC runs. After the GC is done, your **finalizer** will probably be called, so you know that GC has happened.

Note that I doesn't recommend this and that behaviour is not guaranteed.

If you just want to know when GC runs for curiosity and educational purposes you can use a **clr memory profiler** tool which usually shows you when and how often GC happens and which objects get collected.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. You only have a `Dispose` method on your class when you implement an `IDisposable`. This is for freeing up resources. It gets called when the object "destructs". Garbage collection itself is a **black box**.

For more information, check: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx

Answer (score 1):

in .NET 4, you can use [Garbage Collection Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc713687.aspx)